# Docker dev environment, pylint unable to import error

Tags: python, django, docker, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a problem, I have been using a docker environment for my django 2.0 project and pylint was working fine but now it's showing the unable to import module error. I'm aware that the import error question has been asked many times but it was always for a venv setup rather than docker environment setup.

I'm not sure what triggered the error, but possibly because I deleted my old containers, volumes, images and started from scratch.

I'm using Python 3 and VSCode on Manjaro Linux.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

To add "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"] in settings results in real errors not being reported too.

Comment: try to re-build the container/image

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: log-into your  container, open Django shell, then try to import pylint

Comment: Where do you get the error? from `docker` ? or from `manjaro os`?

Comment: Errors in VSCode.  Same errors appear if I run pylint from a terminal.

Comment: Do you mean do a pip install pylint in the container's terminal?

Comment: Whats the output of `pylint --version` ? run this from VSCode terminal

Comment: pylint 2.0.1
astroid 2.0.1
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 27 2018, 13:11:40)
[GCC 8.1.1 20180531]

Comment: How do you get the error? Can you post the error traceback ?

Comment: pi/views.py:4:0: E0401: Unable to import 'rest_framework.views' (import-error)

Comment: post full traceback to question

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

To try and find an answer for myself and anyone who read this, a possible reason for this is installing pylint via vscode which uses pip. Generally not recommended to do this or sudo pip install in linux. Use your linux package manager to install.